# Expandable row in Angular Material with mat-row directives

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Hi I am trying to achieve something similar to [expandable panel](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vjjyayoqjno) but with `mat-row` directives. I am struggling with some css issues that the panel with details info is always visible and is not able to hide. Moreover there is an additional row eveytime visible eventhough I hide the panel. My code looks like [that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9j8ap).

Can anyone help me with this subtle thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear what exactly your question is, but I think this get's what you are currently missing:

1st: Add the following css class:

```
.hide-me {
  display:none;
}
```

And then you can conditionally set the class with ngClass:

```
[ngClass]="{'hide-me': expandedElement !== row}"
```

Or for the row:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" 
    [ngClass]="{'hide-me': expandedElement !== row}" 
    class="example-detail-row"></mat-row>
```

And it solves the obvious question at least:

[image]